# How do I update Apple-hosted content without breaking old app versions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, compatibility, updates

I'm having a memory game in the store using Apple-hosted content for in-app purchases. The content is basically images - users can download new card packs for the game.

I now want to update those images, and they'll have a different size. In parallel I will update the app so that it can handle these new sizes. But how can I avoid the old app versions to download the new sizes? I'm sure that would mess everything up.

I can't find any settings in iTunes Connect that would allow me to set compatibility relationships or something. Does anyone have an idea how to manage this situation?

Comment: Did you find a solution as I am facing the exact same issue?

Comment: No sorry, eventually I had to include the old in-App purchases for free in the bundle, and add the new ones as usual. They really should find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a pain you can update the newer version of the app to use slightly different image names.  That way you retain the original app functionality while the new version uses the new images.  It's more work, but as more people upgrade to newer versions of your app you can phase out the old images.

Comment: While that is true, it would also mean to add a second in-App purchase bundle for each product with the new image names, which would require all customers to re-purchase the same product just because the internal naming convention has changed :-/

Comment: Oh well, it was just a thought.  Maybe Apple can add some versioning to the hosted content sometime soon.  That would certainly fix the problem.